# What is a w/t ratio?

Tags: simplify3d

I have seen a few guides mentioning *w/t ratio* but I can't find anything which defines it.

I am using Simplify3D with a Wanhao i3.

Comment: Can you put the question into a context? What is the ratio referring to? A printer? Filament? Software? Presumably, you are referring to guides about Simplify 3D? Can you edit your question and provide links to, and quotes from, these guides, showing where _w/t_ is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to refer to calibration factor called *Width over Thickness*.

From [Calibrate your 3D printer to print parts to fit](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:52946)

> Here is the list of necessary variables for this calibration to work,
>
> - Carve/Extra Decimal Places (float) : change to 5
> - Carve/Edge Width over Height (ratio) : nozzle diameter/layer height
> - Inset/Infill **Width over Thickness** (ratio) : nozzle diameter/layer height (initially)
> - Dimension/Filament Packing Density (ratio) : needs calibration (equivalent to the reciprocal of the extrusion multiplier in Slic3r)
> - Scale/XY Plane Scale (ratio) : needs calibration